# Flexbox to align content in footer?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Okay, I have been trying to get the content in my footer to align equally on cross and main axis.

- **All three divs need to be spaced out in the footer to have equal space around them and the center div i.e. red div has to be 2x ratio
  of the other divs** (As is currently, except not spaced out properly)
- **the height of all the divs should be the the same as red div.** **Notice:** that the green div is smaller is height and the orange div is larger.

---

this is what the footer looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwtW7.jpg

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: if you share the code , people can help by modify the code, - add `flex: 1` to all the three columns, even though if content is over the flexbox specified space then other columns will shrink , to avoid this use overflow: hidden / scroll , flexwrap ..

Answer (score 0):

See below.

```css
footer {
background: blue;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
padding: 2em;
}
.green {
background: green;
width: 20%;
}
.red {
background: red;
width: 40%;
}
.orange {
background: orange;
width: 20%
};
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="green">Text</div>
<div class="red">Text</div>
<div class="orange">Text</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image you shared, i have created this fiddle using flexbox
https://jsfiddle.net/1r39tfc9/1/

Adjust the height of your footer according to your needs. Hope this helps.

```
<style>
    footer {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      -webkit-align-items: stretch;
      align-items: stretch;
      height:200px;
    }

    .box {
      padding: 20px;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .green {
      background: green;
      flex:1;
    }
    .red {
      background: red;
      flex:2;
    }
    .orange {
      background: orange;
      flex:2;
    }
</style>

     <footer>
      <div class="box green">
        Green
      </div>
      <div class="box red">
        Red
      </div>
      <div class="box orange">
        Orange
      </div>
    </footer>
```